# Array value must start with "{" or dimension information when excute_values to jsonb column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

My codes

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter

register_adapter(dict, Json)

data = [{
    'end_of_epoch_data': ['GasCoin', [{'Input': 5}, {'Input': 6}, {'Input': 7}]],
}]

def get_upsert_sql(schema: str, table: str, columns: str, primary_keys: list | tuple | set):
    return f"""INSERT INTO {schema}.{table}
            ({', '.join(columns)}) VALUES %s
            ON CONFLICT ({','.join(primary_keys)}) DO UPDATE
            SET {', '.join([f"{col}=EXCLUDED.{col}" for col in columns if col not in primary_keys])}"""


def upsert(data: list, uri: str, schema: str, table: str, primary_keys: list | tuple | set):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(uri)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        columns = data[0].keys()
        query = get_upsert_sql(schema, table, columns, primary_keys)
        values = [[d[col] for col in columns] for d in data]
        execute_values(cursor, query, values)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        connection.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

but I got errors like

```
  File "/Users/tests/test_pg_write.py", line 47, in upsert
    execute_values(cursor, query, values)
  File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 1299, in execute_values
    cur.execute(b''.join(parts))
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "GasCoin"
LINE 2:             (end_of_epoch_data) VALUES (ARRAY['GasCoin',ARRA...
                                                      ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

`end_of_epoch_data` is jsonb column in postgres table

any idea? thanks

**UPDATE**

it seems that the error is because i tried to write python list to jsonb column in pg table. but it seems that i can write `json.dumps(dataend_of_epoch_data)` which is str of python list into jsonb column of postgres table... is this right solution?

Comment: Let me guess: the data type is `jsonb[]`. That is usually the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of turning data into a list of lists, write it as is:

```python
#values = [[d[col] for col in columns] for d in data] #no
values = [json.dumps(d['end_of_epoch_data']) for d in data] #yes
```

If `end_of_epoch_data` is declared as a column type `text`, `json` or `jsonb` PostgreSQL will accept that as a valid literal. If you try writing list of lists like the one you have, PostgreSQL won't accept it [no matter what type of column you're saving it to](https://dbfiddle.uk/8v4-WROV).

---

The reason you're getting the error is PostgreSQL [array requirements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT):

> Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension.

This:

```python
values = [[d[col] for col in columns] for d in data]
print(values[0])
#[['GasCoin', [{'Input': 5}, {'Input': 6}, {'Input': 7}]]]
```

Gets you Python arrays (lists) which are [ok in Python](https://www.online-python.com/WtM0Q1Gy2s):

```python
my_python_list_of_lists = ['1dim',['2dim',['3dim']]]
print(type(my_python_list_of_lists),my_python_list_of_lists)
#<class 'list'> ['1dim', ['2dim', ['3dim']]]
```

but [won't work in PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/36vyj6mM), because of the requirement up top:

```sql
create table test as select array['1dim',array['2dim',array['3dim']]];
```

> ```
> ERROR:  malformed array literal: "2dim"
> LINE 1: create table test as select array['1dim',array['2dim',array[...
>                                                        ^
> DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
> ```

The first element is a flat, non-array, scalar `text`. The second element is an array (in your case, of objects/dictionaries, but PostgreSQL doesn't make far enough to mind). When you give that to PostgreSQL, it reads the first element, considers the option the whole incoming thing might be a simple `text[]`, one-dimensional array of `text`. Then it proceeds to the second element which turns out to be explicitly `ARRAY[]`. To hold that, the value would have to be `text[][]`, not just `text[]`.

For that to work, the first value would also have to be `ARRAY[]` - or coercible thereto - in order to achieve the *array of matching extents*. [Here's](https://dbfiddle.uk/bV5PuvhW) an example where that could've worked:

```sql
create table test 
as (values (array['{a,b,c}',--this is `text`, but it could also work as `text[]`
                  array['d','e','f']
                 ]
           )
   );
```

| column1 | array_dims |
| --- | --- |
| {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}} | [1:2][1:3] |

The first `text` element turns out to be a valid array literal, so it's interpreted as such, arriving at a 2x3 array.

These [also wouldn't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/x5S2CsSk), because even though the elements are coercible, the nested arrays aren't equal:

```
create table test as (values (array['{a,b,c,d}',array['d','e','f']]));
select column1,array_dims(column1) from test;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
> ```

```
create table test as (values (array['{a,b,c}',array['d','e','f','g']]));
select column1,array_dims(column1) from test;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
> ```

Comment: thanks.

i have a jsonb column. (1) we can write python dict to it. if pg will convert integer key into string key....

(2) if it is python list, we can write `json.dumps(python_list)` to it...